# Add delimiter | to Google Charts Labels

Tags: google-visualization

How can I write the | delimiter in a Google Charts Label? I've tried many combinations without success.... For example, I want to chart visits on my blog and in my blog page titles there is the | symbol that split the page title from the blog title, for example, the title for this page

http://www.strx.it/2011/04/pagetitle-web-service-on-duostack/

is

"PageTitle web service on Duostack | Strx Blog"

As you can see, in the title there is the | char and plotting it to google charts seems not possible...any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the pipe character? So:

"PageTitle web service on Duostack \| Strx Blog"